# Adding descriptions to the shadowbox image

Tags: javascript, shadowbox

I am trying to add a description to an image. I know you can add titles but I'm looking for a description and title. Can anyone tell me the best way to accomplish this, or if it's even possible?

thanks in advance

Comment: What plugin are you using if any ? Where is your code ? To get accurate answers, you should provide necessary details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `title` attribute with some HTML like below:

```
<a href="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" rel="shadowbox;height=200;width=200" title="<b>My Image</b><span>Desc</span>">My Image</a>​
```

And use the CSS to make it work!

```css
#sb-title, #sb-title-inner {height: 3em;}
#sb-title-inner b {display: block; font-size: 1.2em;}
#sb-title-inner span {display: block;}​
```

Check out the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bagFr/) here. Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Oh okay, yeah, but I just gave the `height` and `width` else it was showing very ugly!